# Google groups not finding discussion thread but regular google search does?

Tags: google-search, google-groups

I'm having a problem with google groups and finding my own discussion threads. I go to the google group (in my case Android developer group) web view and try to search for my thread by entering the extact title of my thread. But it doesn't appear in the search results.

On the other hand, when I search for the same title in the regular google web search, I get the thread right on top of the result list.

I thought it might take a while until the groups index all new threads, but still after a few days, it still wouldn't show up.

Sample:

My thread is here:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0ab41d5056a25ce7

Doing a search for it in Google groups (will give one result, but not mine):
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/search?group=android-developers&q=Strange+behaviour+with+mediaplayer+and+seekTo&qt_g=Search+this+group

Search in Google web search (shows my thread as first result):
http://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Strange+behaviour+with+mediaplayer+and+seekTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, Google Groups search quality has deteriorated in recent years.  The search results are wonky, particularly over its Usenet archives.  Here is an article regarding that from 2009: http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2009/10/usenet/

Google has stated there was a single bug causing failure of its Usenet search and has been repaired, but I still often see unreasonable search results.

This question is asking about search over native Google Groups and not Usenet, but it would not be surprising if the two are related.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the article. It's still pretty recent (10/2009). I guess it's related to my issue. Can't believe Google with it's main business being a search engine doesn't offer proper groups search.